# How old is Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, users, statistics

Simple enough question. I notice Stack Overflow has over 100,000 users — huge congrats guys! Can you share exactly how old Stack Overflow is? Also, what percentage of the 100,000 are active? Can you provide any statistical breakdown on the activity?

Thoroughly impressed and looking forward to Stack Overflow's bright future.

UPDATE: I have found some fascinating statistics via Twitter for Stack Overflow. They do not provide a complete answer to my question, but some interesting details may be derived. For example, how many visits / person etc.

http://www.quantcast.com/p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc

Comment: Ok, so I think going from the private beta or July 31, 2008 makes the most sense, since that's when the site actually started accumulating users. So Olafur Waage, jjnguy, wallaceno9, and Henk Holterman all reach that same conclusion in a different way.

So... what about my second question? What percentage of the 100,000 users are active? Just curious!

Answer (score 14):

[Question #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1/where-oh-where-did-the-joel-data-go) was asked July 31st, 2008 21:26:37Z.

Unfortunately its timeless wisdom was deleted and is now only visible to those with 10k rep or more.

[Question #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4/when-setting-a-forms-opacity-should-i-use-a-decimal-or-double) (Post ID is 4), visible to all, was asked shortly after at 21:42:52Z

The [public beta](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/then-a-miracle-occurs-public-beta/) opened September 15th, 2008.  This is the point that Stackoverflow was officially open to one and all.

Comment: I'll let you savor the moment you become a 10k user by not giving away the contents of the question.

Comment: It looks like I joined on September 17th, 2008. I didn't realize that I joined just 2 days after the site went public.

Answer (score 13):

Well, the [private beta started July 31st 2008](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/stack-overflow-private-beta-begins/).

Answer (score 6):

From April 16, 2008:

[Introducing Stackoverflow.com](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001101.html)

Answer (score 5):

As old as the [community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1) is.

Also you could look at when [Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1) became a member.

Comment: No real time when Jeff Atwood became a member (just says 1 year) -- or I missed it on the page somehow. Also the 'community' link shows the age that a moderation background process was created -- apparently after real users :)

Comment: Josh: hover on the "*member for*" number and there will be a tooltip saying `2008-07-31`

Answer (score 4):

In the **Stack Exchange - All Sites** page, in the **list view** with **Sort by: Oldest** you can find all the site's age in descending order.

Or simply use this URL for the same option: https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#oldest

> [image: Any SE site's age]

Note: It won't say when was the sites were started. But giving the site's current age.

---

**Another option to check the each site's starting date:**

In any site, when you are navigate to the **Users** -> **reputation** tab -> hover the **all** tab it will display the text as *starting date of the site* to today.

For Stack Overflow the starting date is `2008-07-31`

The URL path is: https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all

[image: Stack Overflow starting date]