# What days did the trilogy sites launch on?

Tags: discussion

Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Super User and Meta all launched on different days, does anyone know the dates exactly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Stack Overflow: [July 31st, 2008 21:26](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1) (deleted, 10k rep can see it)
- Server Fault: [April 30th, 2009 6:49](https://serverfault.com/questions/1)
- Meta: [June 28th, 2009 7:14](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1) (deleted, 10k rep can see it)
- Super User: [July 15th, 2009 6:27](https://superuser.com/questions/1)

Comment: Summertime and the livin' is easy / Fish are jumpin' and the cotton is high

Answer (score 3):

Stack Overflow: September 15, 2008 for Public Beta.

Server Fault: May 26, 2009 for Public Beta.

Super User: July 14, 2009 for Semi-Private beta, August 18, 2009 for full launch

Meta: Some time between SF and SU Beta.

SO and SF had a private beta before and launched a month or so after, couldn't find the exact dates right now.

Answer (score 0):

The official ages of the trilogy sites are:

- stack**overflow**: [1 year](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1)
- server**fault**: [7 months](https://serverfault.com/users/-1)
- super**user**: [5 months](https://superuser.com/users/-1)
- *Meta*stack**overflow**: [5 months](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1)

If I'm not mistaken, the "member for" field is reffering to post-beta dates. You have to add some time if you want to count the beta time.

Comment: These are necessarily inexact, I'm hoping for "launch dates."

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30128/how-old-is-stackoverflow