# The starting day of the site is displaying wrongly

Tags: bug, tooltips

In **Users** page -> **Reputation** tab -> [**all**](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) option is for sorting the users by reputation in descending order from the starting day of the site to today. When hover on the **all** option the tooltip is displaying the text, in the format of `starting-date-of-the-site to today`. Currently the starting date of the site is displaying wrongly.

For an example, in Stack Overflow previously it was displayed as [`2008-07-31 to today`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279306/312043), currently it is displaying as `2000-01-01 to today`. The issue is for all Stack Exchange sites.

**Current behavior**:

> [image: Current behavior]

---

**Old behavior:**

> [image: Old behavior]